# Eliminate the need to write to a file using python for a specific output

Tags: python

I am using the below codes so as to get the output as (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
using for loop.To achieve the required output I am writing the values to a file and then reading it back into python.The question is, is there any method to avoid writing into a file for reading the values.Please refer the codes below.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    fo=open('A.txt','a')
    fo.write(str(i)+",")
    fo.close()

fo1=open('A.txt','r')
input= "("+fo1.read()[0:len(fo1.read())-1]+")"
fo1.close()

import os
os.remove('A.txt')
print input

#THE OUTPUT IS BELOW
#(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Comment: Why don't you use variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'd like to use

```
print("(" + ",".join([str(n) for n in range(1,11)]) + ")")
```

Writing to a file is definitely overkill and unneeded in this case

```
In [2]:     print("(" + ",".join([str(n) for n in range(1,11)]) + ")")
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: @ThierryLathuille fixed!